# Title tag on unanswered pages doesn't change even when filered by tag

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, title

Just wondering, shouldn't the title of pages such as:

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/c#

Be something other than simply:

```
Unanswered Questions
```

Surely

```
Unanswered C# Questions
```

Would be better for both search engines and users when attempting to choose the correct page from some search results?

Answer (score 1):

At https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/c%23 when you click on another tag name under "Unanswered Tags" on  the right sidebar, say ".net", you will be browsing https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/c%23+.net or rather "Unanswered c# and .net questions".

Hence having the title to include the tag names is not that straightforward.

I do agree that it could have been more informative, but I'm fine with the way it is now.